# Event not firing for static mark up in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I have a simple todo List where each task is added by click or enter

```
   <div className="taskControll">
      <input type='text' name="newTask" id="newTask" onKeyDown={(e)=>{keyCheck(e)}}/> 
      <input type='button' name="addTask" value='add' onClick = {addTask}  /> 
  </div>
```

'addTask' adds a task to taskController div, the function is as follows

```
function addTask(){

    let task = document.getElementById("newTask").value;
    document.getElementById("newTask").value = '';
    let taskViewer = document.getElementById("tasks");
    const data = renderToStaticMarkup
                                  (
                                  <div><span>{task}</span>                                        
                                    <input type='checkbox' name="doneTask" id = {task} value='done' onClick={(e)=>{strikeTask(e)}}/> 
                                  <br></br></div>);
    taskViewer.innerHTML += data;
```

}

I am adding an onclick function 'strikeTask' to each check box so that each task is crossed out when check box is checked

```
 function strikeTask(e){
     console.log(e);
     //do stuff
 }
```

The problem is, while both method 'keycheck'(call addTask on 'enter') and 'addTask' work just fine I just cannot get the strikeTask method to fire I have tried both arrow and anonymous function

```
onClick={(e)=>{strikeTask(e)}}
```

But if I do

```
onClick={strikeTask(this)}
```

The function is fired by itself when the task is added i.e this is seen as a call to function not as a reference to it. I can also see that event is not being added to check box when I inspect it in the browser I suspect this is because I have used 'renderToStaticMarkup' to add tasks to the list. How can I get the event to fire only when checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's late but I figured it out, using 'innerHTML' empties the target div and then insert new elements which causes the event listener to be removed. I was able to resolve the issue using 'insertAdjacentHTML' as it keeps the event listeners intact. Thanks for the replies anyway

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox needs an onChange `onChange={(e)=>{strikeTask(e)}}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot to include that I tried onChange as well, not working

Comment: What is the `renderToStaticMarkup` doing?
Altogether, it probably would be a better idea to do conditional rendering + state to render the checkboxes.

Comment: 'renderToStaticMarkup' converts jsx elements to plain html other the div gets populated with [objects objects]

Comment: I'm not sure, but I have a feeling that if it gets rendered to plain html the reference to `strikeTask()` gets lost as it is not inside of the original jsx component, makes sense?

Comment: Well, that's what I thought too as I cannot see the event when I inspect the checkboxes but how exactly does it gets lost? how is it not a part of jsx component? Isn't everything that is referenced in the by the component should be included?